# How to use arrayformula in googlesheet to count the column with condition?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, countif

[image]

Hi everyone,

I'm trying to count the number of "Yes" appeared in each row. I want to use array formula so that I'm not required to have formula in each cell in column G. May I know arrayformula can achieve this or there is other method? I tried to use `arrayformula(countif(B4:F4,"Yes"))` but nothing come out for row 5,6,7,8. Hope to get some advice on this problem as I'm new to google sheet. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(IF(B4:F="Yes", ROW(B4:B8)), ROW(B4:B8)))`

**Edit**: For the case that you describe below (only including certain columns), it's a little more involved, but the same principle works.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(IF(B4:B="Yes", ROW(B4:B8)), ROW(B4:B8)) + COUNTIF(IF(D4:D="Yes", ROW(D4:D8)), ROW(D4:D8)) + COUNTIF(IF(F4:F="Yes", ROW(F4:F8)), ROW(F4:F8)))`

Comment: Hi Oakley, thanks for your reply. I'm sorry that My example is not good enough. If there is a "Yes" in column C, of column E, how should I skip the count in column C & E?

Comment: @weizer are you looking to just exclude column E from the count?

Comment: I just want to include column B, column D and column F to count how many "Yes", so let say if cell C4 is a "Yes", then it will exclude it from the count since it is not within column B,D or F. Thanks for your reply:)

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Do you think this formula `ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(IF(B4:B="Yes", ROW(B4:B8)), ROW(B4:B8)) + COUNTIF(IF(D4:D="Yes", ROW(D4:D8)), ROW(D4:D8)) + COUNTIF(IF(F4:F="Yes", ROW(F4:F8)), ROW(F4:F8)))` will run faster or I use query function to select column B,D,F then only use countif() without using arrayformula?

Comment: Honestly the query and arrayformula functions are two of the slowest you can use in a google sheet, so either way you will likely see some slowness if your dataset is very large. Overall, I tend to use arrayformula for calculations and query to reorganize data. https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/slow-google-sheets/ This link has some tips for optimizing google sheets if you're interested.

Comment: Thank you! The link you share is very useful, it reduce the time for calculation:)